# Insert queries for a customer purchase

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I am designing a database that includes sales.

Based on questions related to the schema for similar situations, I have made 4 relevant tables with the following columns below. However I have not found questions/answers related to the queries used to make a purchase. I am trying to work out how to make a stored procedure where I can make a purchase, insert the PurchaseID as a foreign key in the "PurchasedProducts" table for each ProductID foreign key for the products bought.

> Students:
>
> StudentID |...
>
> Purchases:
>
> PurchaseID | StudentID | PurchaseDate | PaymentStatus | AmountPaid |
>   Discounts
>
> PurchasedProducts (many to many table):
>
> PPID | PurchaseID | ProductID | ProductQuantity
>
> Products:
>
> ProductID | ... | StandardPrice

To open up another can of worms, the "amountpaid", "discount" columns are in the purchases table (If they don't belong in this table please let me know). A "total cost" column would also probably be needed. However these would be based on calculations using the "standard price" from the products table. How do I incorporate this into the query?

One of the main issues i'm facing when trying to work out this query is working out how to set parameters for productIDs that vary in number for each purchase.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can help you but we need to know what you need help with. There really isn't much of a question here. The only place where you ask a question is about incorporating some unknown calculation into an unknown query. There seems to be some interesting stuff in your design here. How is PurchasedProducts a many to many relationship? Wouldn't each row here represent a single item number that belongs to a specific purchase?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity - The issue here is i'm trying to work out what the query would look like myself to begin with. The PurchasedProducts table is the one that makes a many to many relationship between the products and purchases table. i.e Many purchases can involve many products. So the many to many relationship is between the tables: Purchases and Products.

Comment: Well if you figure out what your question is let us know.

Comment: My question: what would the query look like? it inserts the relevant data into the Purchases and PurchasedProducts table

Comment: You would have an insert into Purchases and a second insert into PurchasedProducts. They would look like every other insert statement.

Comment: If each row in the PurchasedProducts table would/could have different products for the same purchase, is there a way to set up parameters for a varying number of ProductIDs to be inserted in multiple rows for the same purchase? e.g - create procedure @ProductID int ... would account for 1 Product, but in any one purchase a student could buy 2,3,4... products.

Comment: The most common way to deal with this is to call an insert procedure for each item that is purchased in a loop. Another option would be to use a table valued parameter and pass the entire collection of items ordered. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine As it sits right now this question is both too vague and too broad to be considered on topic for SO.